# How to parse <div @class = 'myclass' element1 element2 element3> using Hpple for iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, hpple, tfhpple

I have a html file that has something similar to

```
<div @class = 'myclass' element1 element2 element3>
```

How do I parse it to fetch element1, elemnet2 and element3?

I am using Hpple for iOS.

I am using query like

```
NSString *elementsXpathQueryString = @"//div[@class='myclass']/a";
```

but it doesn't work out.

TIA

Comment: That doesn't look like valid HTML.

Comment: Hmm well, many sites are using this format. And I need to parse it to display on iOS.

Comment: Have you tried getting the keys of `TFHppleElement`s `attributes` dictionary?

Comment: yes but the elements list keep on changing with every html response. It can be e1, e2, e3 initially but it may be e1 only with next response. How to fetch these values?

Comment: Please see my edits for query string.

Comment: Those aren't elements; they're attributes. as HAS said those are accessible via the "attributes" method as an NSDictionary object. The "count" method for that class will return you the number of attributes in the dictionary.

Comment: Don't understand whether have `<div class = "myclass" attrib0 = "value0" attrib1 = "value1">` or `<div class = "myclass"> elem0  elem1 </div>` - how to get data will depend on which!